# dig @nameserver doesn't work

Tags: dns, bind

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with BIND9, working just as a caching server (forwarding to 8.8.8.8).

When I use, for example, `dig +norecurse @l.root-servers.net www.uniroma1.it`, I obtain the following output

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> +norecurse @l.root-servers.net www.uniroma1.it
>
> ; (1 server found)
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Using Wireshark I discovered that the outgoing queries are correct, but there aren't any incoming answers. Why?

P.S. Using simply `dig www.uniroma1.it` I obtain the correct answers.

Comment: I asume that when you use just `dig` without `@<nameserver>` it uses your own dns server that you setup and specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`? Did you firewall yourself?

Comment: In `/etc/resolv.conf` is present only the 127.0.0.1 server, and I think it's right. I've no firewall, but probably my ISP does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command works fine here.  My guess is that a firewall, either at your location or at your ISP, is blocking the DNS requests or responses.  The normal `dig www.uniroma1.it` likely works because said firewall is allowing requests to certain servers, like the ones provided by your ISP and maybe `8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 2):

The Root servers will not answer queries for domains that they are not authoritative for. If you run the command without the +norecurse argument, it should return a list of referrals for the .it domain. You will never get an A record response from the Root servers.

Comment: But you should get NS records in an AUTHORITY section, not "connection timed out".

Comment: @Jim Paris But my answer wasnt wrong. Why did you down vote it? You only answered part of the question yourself. You didnt address the fact that he was querying the root servers directly, which was the first part of his problem

Comment: I downvoted because it is wrong.  The root servers **will** answer queries, with a NS record pointing to the next server in the hierarchy that may be able to answer.  They will **not** simply drop queries and send no response, which is what the asker was seeing.

Comment: I never said that it will drop queries. No where in my answer said it will drop queries. If you can point out in my answer where I said that it will drop queries, you can have those points. If you read further you will see that I mentioned that root will give referrals for the .it domain. I didn't specifically address his time out issue. I addressed the fact that he was asking root for an A record.

Comment: You said: "Root servers will not answer queries".  The root server **will** answer.  It will say, "I don't know, here are the nameservers to ask next."  Anyway, regardless of how nitpicky you want to get, your answer was not useful, which is exactly what a downvote is for.  The asker was having problems with a firewall blocking replies, and you discussed unrelated details about how root nameservers don't include A responses in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `dig @nameserver domain.example.com` does not work for specific nameservers only, while working for the large majority of them, it can also be an issue of that nameserver blocking traffic from some sources. They probably only want to answer to other nameservers (?). Obviously that's bad behavior because it makes debugging DNS issues harder.

This does not apply to the root server example posted in the question. But, for example, I see this behavior consistently with the nameservers of DNS hoster DomainDiscount24:

```
dig @ns1.domaindiscount.net example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1ubuntu2.2-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.domaindiscount.net example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

(Using `example.com` is an example, but even that should yield an answer pointing me to the right nameserver for the `example.com` domain. But the same behavior as shown above applies when using a domain actually hosted at DomainDiscount24.)